# How to retrieve single record for a column based on SQL Server CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, case-statement

I am trying to write a SQL Server CASE statement to retrieve a student's category based on the following condition.

If the `category` column from the `student_category` table has both values 'X' and 'Y' for a `student_id` value from the `student` table, then only display the record where value is 'Y'.

If the `category` has either values 'X' or 'Y', then display the records with that value.

If the `category` does not have values 'X' or 'Y', display a blank for the column i.e. if there are any other categories except 'X' or 'Y', display a blank.

Thus, I should only have one row of data for each `student_id` even if they have multiple categories. However, I am still getting multiple records for each `student_id` with more than one category. Any ideas on what I might be missing ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.student_id,
    CASE
       WHEN sc.category = 'X' AND sc.category = 'Y' THEN 'Y'
       WHEN sc.category = 'X' OR sc.category = 'Y' THEN sc.category
       ELSE ''
    END AS student_cat
FROM
    student s
LEFT JOIN
    student_category sc ON s.student_id = sc.student_id
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: case *expression* not *statement*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having two rows returned because, regardless of what conditions you put in that CASE statement of yours, for a certain student ID, there are two records from the join between student and student_category. Without some sort of aggregation, you will have two rows.

There are a few ways to solve this. This is how I would do it:

```
SELECT  s.student_id,
        --Check how many of each category there are for the student
        CASE WHEN sc.Number_of_x = 1 AND sc.Number_of_y = 1 THEN 'Y'
             WHEN sc.Number_of_x = 1 AND sc.Number_of_y = 0 THEN 'X'
             WHEN sc.Number_of_x = 0 AND sc.Number_of_y = 1 THEN 'Y'
                                                            ELSE ''
        END AS student_cat
FROM    student AS s
        LEFT JOIN (
                  --Aggregate the categories per student so that we only have 1 line
                  --per student_id
                  SELECT    student_id,
                            SUM( IIF( sc.category = 'X', 1, 0 ) ) AS Number_of_x,
                            SUM( IIF( sc.category = 'Y', 1, 0 ) ) AS Number_of_y,
                  FROM      student_category AS sc
                  GROUP BY  student_id
                  ) AS sc
            ON      s.student_id = sc.student_id
```

This way you first aggregate the student_category table in a sub-query to return 1 row per student, then check those counts to determine the category.

This is assuming the only categories are X and Y, and there can only ever be 0 or 1 of either category.

I find it helps to just write SELECT * with a sample of the data before writing queries using DISTINCT or CASE statement to see what it looks like raw, and how many rows there are.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation.

```
select s.student_id, min(sc.category) as student_cat
from student s left join
     student_category sc
     on s.student_id = sc.student_id
group by s.student_id;
```

I can't tell from your question; you might want `max()` instead of `min()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by s.student_id order by sc.category desc) as rn
    from student s left outer join student_category sc
        on s.student_id = sc.student_id
)
select * from data where rn = 1;
```

This will let you bring along other columns or to incorporated more sophisticated sorting logic as needed.